# Фразеологизм или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология

Здесь, как я понимаю, без запятых:

> Он делает это как заблагорассудится;

> Он берет что угодно.

А если так ли?

`Он делает это(,) как ему заблагорассудится`;

`Он берет(,) что ему угодно`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Он все делает по-своему. Делает **как заблагорассудится**. Делает **как хочет*** (= по-своему).

Но: *Он делает **это**, как **ему** заблагорассудится.*

*Ему можно предложить всё.  Он берет **что угодно*** (= безразлично что).

Он берет, что **емУ** угодно (= по своему желанию). Иногда трудно понять, что ему предложить.

Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой
Что Угодно, мест.
1.**Что хочешь, безразлично что.** 2.
**То, что соответствует желанию; всё, что хочешь.**

[https://znachenie-slova.ru/фразеологизм/что-душе-угодно](https://znachenie-slova.ru/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

[https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/что+угодно](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Comment: То есть местоимение таки избавляет словосочетание от фразеологического значения?

Comment: Думаю, что да. Нужно контактное расположение глагола и оборота, а также его минимальный объем. Тогда можно прочитать предложение без паузы, в одну фонетическую фразу.